# Ethereum Wallet and Mist stuck on block 1,699,999 even after updating to latest version of geth

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, wallets, synchronization, clients

`geth version
Geth
Version: 1.7.2-stable
Git Commit: 1db4ecdc0b9e828ff65777fb466fc7c1d04e0de9
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.9.1
Operating System: darwin
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.9.1/libexec`

[image]

Here - https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/15185 - they suggest updating but I'm already running latest.

[image]

Mist is also stuck on 1,699,999.

When synchronising Bitcoin blockchain I also had troubles (Bitcoin Core crashing) and the solution was to delete `peers.dat`. Hoping here there is also some magic bullet.

Comment: Someone recommended to try `--nodiscover` to only use the bootnodes from the foundation at least the block 1.7M.

Comment: @Ismael ```cd /Applications/Ethereum\ Wallet.app/Contents/MacOS/``` and ```./Ethereum\ Wallet --nodiscover``` now https://gist.github.com/stefek99/8759c7f4c705dbd983336c67831924b6